# Generalized eigenvalue problem with nonnegative eigenvector constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, quadratic-forms, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Consider the following problem that is known to be non-convex but can be solved as a generalized eigenvalue problem (i.e. has a global optimum solution):

$\underset{w}{\text{maximize}}\quad w^{\top}Qw\\
\underset{w}{\text{minimize}}\quad w^{\top}Pw$

where $P\in\mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ and $Q\in\mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric, PSD and their elements are NOT necessarily non-negative. Also, $w\in\mathcal{R}^{n}$.

We need to solve $\underset{w}{\text{maximize}}\:\frac{w^{\top}Qw}{w^{\top}Pw}$. This can be written as $Qw=\lambda Pw$ and if P is full rank we can convert this to a standard eigenvalue problem: $P^{-1}Qw=\lambda w$.

The problem that I want to solve is similar to above problem except in that the elements of vector $w$ must be non-negative:

$\underset{w}{\text{maximize}}\quad w^{\top}Qw\\
\underset{w}{\text{minimize}}\quad w^{\top}Pw$

$s.t.\qquad w\geq0$

or equivalently $\underset{w}{\text{maximize}}\:\frac{w^{\top}Qw}{w^{\top}Pw}$ s.t. $\: w\geq0$.
What kind of method can be used to solve this?